# CSS flex is not taking the full height of the parent div which is also flex

Tags: flexbox, tailwind-css

I am building a Web application using React. I am using Tailwind CSS to style the UI components. Now, I am having trouble centering the child elements of the flex div which is the child of another flex div.

Here is my code:

```
<div className="flex h-full justify-center items-center">
<div data-page-id={'login-page'} className={"border rounded-3xl shadow w-2/6 min-w-500px min-h-400px bg-primary p-4 flex flex-col"}>
            <div className={"text-center"}>
                <h1 className="text-white text-2xl mb-3">Login</h1>
                <p className="text-white text-xs">Admin portal</p>
            </div>
            <div className={"flex-1"}>
                <div className={"flex flex-col justify-center items-center"}>
                    <h3>Content Title</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium aliquam consectetur debitis
                        distinctio dolor eius esse et illo, ipsam laudantium minus odit officiis quasi reprehenderit
                        sint temporibus ut vero vitae!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

The above code gives me the following output in the browser.

[image]

That is not quite what I am trying to achieve. What I want is I want the flex div in the content section to take the full height of the parent. But it is not taking up the remaining space as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it to take up the full height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I have noticed you're using [arbitrary class values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values) the wrong way. Whenever you want your own value of height, width, etc. It should be passed inside square brackets. Like this `min-w-[500px] min-h-[400px]`

Second, When you used `flex-1` It is expanding row (horizontally), so it will take all available width not height. Because by default `flex-direction` in tailwind is `row`. You need to change it by using `flex flex-col flex-1`. Now your div will expand to the available height. I have made a working example for your case. You can have a look over here https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-montalcini-97x7bx?file=/src/App.js